# While reading response from a socket, I get what I wrote earlier on it

Tags: c, sockets, soap

This is about an implementation test of a soap client with just ANSI C standard libraries for an embedded system.

After sending my HTTP POST request to the server, I'm trying to save the SOAP XML document on `response`. But when I print the response I got, besides the whole XML document, it has appended the last 223 bytes written on the socket.

It doesn't seem that is a memory overlapping issue since `docbuff_size = 1024` and `response` ends with 883 characters. I though that the UTF-8 encoding might be an issue but the I tried with different sizes of `docbuff_size` and `buffer_size` and I always got the same behavior.

If I write my `buffer` on stdout with `fputs` these tailing 223 bytes won't show. I build `response` with `strncpy` from what's in `buffer`. I think the problem is hidden on the different behaviors of these two functions.

This is a digested version of my code

```
...

int n;
char limiter[] = "\r\n\r\n";
bool first = true;
bool limiter_found = false;
char *pDocument = NULL;
char *pTmp = NULL;
unsigned int pDoc_len = 0;
char buffer[buffer_size] = {0};
char midbuff[10] = {0};
char response_code[4] = {0};
bzero(tmp, sizeof(tmp));

char *response;
response = malloc(docbuff_size);
bzero(response, sizeof(response));
bTotal = 0;
while ( (n = read(serverSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1) ) > 0)
{

    buffer[n] = '\0';

    ...

    // Case: limiter found in last iteration, then copy this buffer entirely
    if( pDocument != NULL && (bTotal+strlen(buffer)) < docbuff_size ){
        strncpy(response+bTotal, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        bTotal += strlen(buffer);
    }

    limiter_found = false;
    if( pTmp = strstr(buffer, limiter) ){
        pDocument = pTmp+4;
        limiter_found = true;
    } else if ( !first && (pTmp = strstr(midbuff, limiter)) ){
        // Take out 3 from the tail offset, add 4 from limiter length = 1
        pDocument = buffer + (pTmp - midbuff) + 1;
        limiter_found = true;
    }

    if(limiter_found){
        strncpy(response, pDocument, strlen(pDocument));
        bTotal += strlen(pDocument);
    }

    if(fputs(buffer, stdout) == EOF)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
    }
} 

if( response[0] != 0 ){
    printf("\n\nXML Document: \n"
        "*************************************\n"
        "%s\n"
        "*************************************\n", response);
}

if(n < 0)
{
    printf("\n Read error \n");
} 

if(response){
    free(response);
    response = NULL;
}
```

And this is an excerpt of the output

```
REQUEST SENT:
POST /xxxx/index.php HTTP/1.0
Host: testzzzzz.dev
User-agent: Blahblah
Content-type: text/xml; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-length: 677
SOAPAction: "http://testzzzzz.dev/xxxx/index.php/ActionXXXX"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope  SOAP-  ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ActionXXXX xmlns:ns1="http://testzzzzz.com/xxxx/nusoap" SOAP-ENC:root="1"><v1 xsi:type="xsd:string">Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipisicingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitati</v1></ns1:ActionXXXX></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

HTTP RESPONSE (written by fputs):
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 18:11:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
X-SOAP-Server: DesiteG/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Length: 660
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ActionXXXXResponse xmlns:ns1="http://testzzzzz.com/xxxx/nusoap"><return xsi:type="xsd:string">ResponseStringblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblaResponseString</return></ns1:ActionXXXXResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

XML Document (build by strncpy): 
*************************************
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ActionXXXXResponse xmlns:ns1="http://testzzzzz.com/xxxx/nusoap"><return xsi:type="xsd:string">ResponseStringblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblaResponseString</return></ns1:ActionXXXXResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>type="xsd:string">Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipisicingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitati</v1></ns1:ActionXXXX></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
*************************************
```

If you scroll to the left you can see where the difference between what fputs gets from what strncpy builds. The `while` last two iterations (the buffer gets used two times).
It seems `read` on the last iteration puts some extra data on buffer that `fputs` correctly ignore but strncpy won't.

---- Edit (Solved, but I don't know why)----

Problem solved using strcpy instead of strncpy.
It seems `strlen(buffer)` ignores the `buffer[n] = '\0'` written before.

`strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src));` isn't the same as `strcpy(dest, src);`?

I want to leave this question open until a clear reason is explained.

Comment: You might like to use a debugger to find out what's going on. For gcc compile with symbols using option `-g`, and then run the program using `gdb --args programname arg1 arg2 ... argn`.

Comment: gazing lightly upon the code: `bzero(response, sizeof(response));` seems odd, if `response` is really declared `char*`.

Comment: I'll go with a wild pointer, somewhere in the code you haven't supplied. If that guess turns out to be correct, then it's not really "Solved" and more fun times await you...

Comment: Note also that `bzero` is not ANSI C (last I looked), while ancient old `calloc` certainly is and certainly would have been harder to use incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Ron Burk `bzero(response, sizeof(response));` is wrong.

Changed to the ANSI C compliant `calloc`

`response = calloc( docbuff_size, sizeof(char) );`

Solved the issue with strncpy though I'll use strcpy to improve readability.

What I think it happened is that `response` is being allocated on top of the variable where I wrote the request, then it wasn't being completely zero-ed and since strncpy doesn't add the final `\0` like strcpy does then `response` would become a mix of old and new data.

It's not necessary to use calloc but it saves a line more.